# Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider React native on Build Xcode 13 beta

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode12

I am getting this error when ever I building react native app on Xcode 13 Beta

```
Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider
```

[UPDATE]

[ERROR RUNNING ON XCODE 12](https://github.com/facebookarchive/react-native-fbsdk/issues/794#issuecomment-695217977)

when I am doing that I got that Error

```
Command PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a only new Swift empty file (it's not necessary to create a Bridging Header).